# Is there a way to implement SSO in front of the microservices?

Tags: go, single-sign-on, cas, microservices, beego

Recently I have a project to implement [SSO(Single-Sign-On)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) for multiple web applications based on [Beego Framework](http://beego.me/). The most popular SSO project is [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Authentication_Service), which needs a CAS Server in the center, and a CAS Client before each web application. Unfortunately, it seems that there's not any offical CAS clients written in Golang, except [go-cas/cas](https://github.com/go-cas/cas), and [adanteng/cas](https://github.com/adanteng/cas), which supports Beego.

But the workflow of CAS is a little bit complicated: too many redirections, too many tickets transmitted among the CAS, web apps, and the user browser. I can't figure out why people deploy the Authentication Services in the center of all the web apps, rather than the front, like the following diagram:

[image]

In this diagram, all the requests are forced to be processed in the Authenticate Service first, if authenticated successfully, then generate a session ID, saved in the cookies and Redis which is shared by other microservices. There's not any redirections or tickets at all, only requests transmittion.

So is this diagram possible, or some critical problems I ignored?

## Update 0

The session-sharing way is indeed not scalable and modular as [Nadh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1357978/nadh) counsels. How about transmitting user information, like name, email, etc., in the headers of requests between the auth service and downstream services, like the creative work of Heipei at [nginx-sso](https://heipei.github.io/2015/09/23/nginx-sso-Simple-offline-SSO-for-nginx/)? Is it possible to make it work as an SSO Gateway as Sam Newman sharing in the book [Building Microservices](http://samnewman.io/books/building_microservices/)?

## Update 1

A more detailed diagram is shown as follows, in order to describe my childish idea a little bit clearly, hoping that there is not much misunderstanding from Heipei and Sam Newman.

Rather than handling so many redirections and handshakes, all the requests are processed in the authentication service firstly, which writes user info from MySQL, into the Redis as the session provider, and the HTTP header to transmit to the downstream services, if the request is authenticated successfully.

In this way, the user info is transmitted via HTTP header instead of the above shared-Redis as [Nadh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1357978/nadh) warning, and Redis can be depolyed with the auth service, or shared among auth instances only.

[image]

## Update 2

It seems that Cookie and Session are old-school techs. The cross-domain problem of cookie, and the sharing problem of session are the primary barrier to the scalability and flexibility of the modern web applications. Fortunately, JSON Web Token comes to be the best Single Sign-on solution for multiple lightweight services nowadays, by moving the user info(maybe id is enough) storage from the server side to the client side, and transmitted only if necessary.

Comment: Architecturally, it may be better to not make A and B depend on Redis persistence just to get a session cookie. Only the 'Authentication service' should connect to Redis. A and B should speak to the Authentication service (via an HTTP API or something) to get the session information.

Comment: @Nadh Thanks for the reply. In order to share the session of user info, there's only one session for all the services, each of them set values to the key with a prefix like "appname.sessionname". If A and B communicate with Auth Service, it works exactly as what CAS does. Do you mean CAS pattern is the only choice? Is there other solutions?

Comment: CAS, by definition, is "central". Your method also works in the short term, but it's not very modular or scalable. What if A and B move to a different data centre? Establishing Redis connections over the internet is going to be a pain. Also, every service you create (in whatever language) will have to have Redis drivers and connectivity. Check out this for an overview of different kinds of implementations -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_single_sign-on_implementations

Comment: @Nadh Thanks very much! Your points are exactly what I omitted. CAS is a flexible way indeed to share sessions. My original motivation is to simplify the workflow of request processing, as the API Gateway pattern, which transmits requests by a Nginx server with the `auth_request` mod. A stupid question, why is it pain to connect to the remote Redis server? Doesn't the `redis-cli -h HOST` work well, or complicated security consideration?

Comment: Exposing your Redis server over the internet, just to share sessions, raises security concerns. You'll have to then have strong firewall and security measures in place, adding another point of failure. A simple HTTP API would eliminate such concerns and complexities.

Answer (score 1):

> But the workflow of CAS is a little bit complicated: too many redirections, too many tickets transmitted among the CAS, web apps, and the user browser. I can't figure out why people deploy the Authentication Services in the center of all the web apps, rather than the front, like the following diagram.

You are thinking the old fashioned way, and thats why architects came up in the past with solutions like using portlet-servers for webapplications, session-shared-clusters, and lots of other heavy error-prone system-solutions which ate your cpu, memory or bandwith in ways which you could never predict until the first real life test.

The CAS solution might look complicated on the first move, but you can predict how much logins, traffic and synchronisation data your system will generate and compared to the "old solutions", your system-to-user load will raise linear and not exponential.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! You're so expirenced in the architecture! The "session-shared-cluster" really costs much mem, since there's many sessions are not destroied, and most of users do not logout manually. I just start learning the microservices, is the "API Gateway" pattern, like [Kong](https://getkong.org/), sort of "portlet-servers"?

Comment: Sorry Yang, i don't know anything about Kong.

Comment: I don't know much either. The source code was opened last year. I just start Kong with the [QuickStart](https://getkong.org/docs/0.8.x/getting-started/quickstart/), so I'm wondering the possibility of SSO implementation in that way.